# What does :: sign means in ActiveRecord::Base

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In ruby I read that a class cannot inherit from multiple classes but in rails there is this code:

```
class ApplicationRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.abstract_class = true
end
```

inside `app/models/application_record.rb`

I know about symbols in ruby but what does this `ActiveRecord::Base` mean in the rails application file? I want to know

Answer (score 3):

It's just a namespace separator, as in:

```
module Example
  class Name
  end
end
```

That's `Example::Name`.

It's also used to reference a top-level namespace to avoid ambiguity, as in:

```
module Name
  class Example
  end
end

module Example
  class Name
    def initialize
      @example = ::Name::Example.new
    end
  end
end
```

Where `::` at the start means "from the top", as opposed to the closest possible match, which in this case would be `Example::Name`.

Comment: Is it the same as saying `Example.Name` when you intend to include the Name class from the Example module

Comment: The `.` part means "method call" and there is no method named `Name` here, so that's not equivalent. Where `.` is shorthand for `.send(...)`, as in `X.y` is `X.send(:y)`, the `::` is more like `X::Y` is the same as `X.const_get(:Y)`.

Comment: This is why if you had `module X; Y = :value; end` then `X::Y` gets you that constant. Remember clases and modules are just constants by virtue of having a capitalized first letter, what Ruby uses to signify that.

Comment: On occasion you'll see `X::y` and `X.y` used interchangeably for *class methods*, but I prefer the second form to make it clear it's a method call. In Ruby you don't need to make this explicit, `X::y` does seem ambiguous, whereas `X::y()` makes it clear, but cluttered. `X.y` leaves no confusion as to what's going on.

Comment: Thanks! what about this method `belongs_to :player` in a rails class model. I think this is a method that takes a symbol as an argument, am I correct? If I am then how is this possible? if am not please explain better to me.

Comment: Methods can take whatever they want as arguments, symbols included. Note that `:x` is very different from `::X`. A symbol is just an "internalized string", or a short-hand string constant. All `:x` are equal, but `"x"` may not be the same object as some other `"x"`, making comparisons more expensive. This is why you see symbols used a lot.